# How to make a csv dataset 100% as the output of make_blobs() of sklearn package

Tags: python, arrays, cluster-analysis

I am a newbie in Python, and just want to check, edit, adjust some code for some basic clustering functions.

I have a csv file with about 1000 values divided in two columns, and I want to import it in python environment and have it 100% compatible as the output of make_blobs()

I imported the data and created an array by using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
X = pd.read_csv("/data.csv")
X = X.as_matrix()
```

and I can see successfully see the data as array:

```
> array([[3.094545, 2.106678],
>        [2.886592, 2.029667],
>        [3.016772, 2.23431 ],
>        [2.739621, 1.883947],
>        [3.202192, 2.009674],
>        [3.295198, 1.346389],
>        [2.769266, 2.041654],
>        [2.867035, 2.222251],
>        [2.963459, 2.22474 ],
>        [3.187592, 2.155406],
>        [2.889698, 1.973654],
>        [3.079113, 2.219817],
>        [3.20275 , 1.833527],
>        [3.008534, 2.005787],
>        [3.16477 , 2.050318],
>        [2.7942  , 1.685328],
>        [3.159495, 2.02407 ],
>        [3.058299, 1.428027],
>        [3.092592, 1.923008],
```

. The problem is that when using:

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples = 300, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.5,
                            random_state=0)
```

A second variable named as labels_true contains values that vary from 0 to 2.

I was wondering on what I could do, to have the "data.csv" file have the same outputs as the X, and labels_true

Answer (score 0):

Your data is unlabeled.

If you had labels, you would not need clustering.

`make_blobs` is synthetics so it also can generate the "correct" labels, but you will have to do without.